# Nrwl NX: Provide style variables from apps to libs

Tags: angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I'll get down straight to the idea:

I want my lib's components to not have specific colors. So I style my component in the following way:

```
h1 {
  color: $primary;
}
```

Note that I do not declare `$primary` variable anywhere in the lib.

I do this in my app's folder (style.scss):

```
$primary: red
```

Obviously, it doesn't work, since I have to import this variable into my lib's component styles. But the library should not depend on the application.

So, the question:

Is it even possible to provide variables to libs from apps? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know how to achieve this using SCSS variables, but with CSS I do:

Lib's component styles:

```
h1 {
  color: var(--primary);
}
```

App's styles:

```
:root {
  --primary: red;
}
```

Comment: Does this not violate boundaries though? Lib is aware of app styles? Supposing you have two apps and app #1 has CSS vars but app #2 does not and lib attempts to use these vars.